# How to handle File Object for gapi savetodrive src?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

In my react app, I have a file object and I want to upload this file to google drive.

I tried to use window.URL.createObjectURL, but the uploaded file on google drive is HTML code of my site instead of the file "f.mp4".

Is there anybody know how to upload file object to google drive in browser????

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url); 

        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onload = function () {
            let gDoxBlob = xhr.response;
            let file = new File([gDoxBlob], "f.mp4", {
                type: 'video/mp4'
            })
            let newUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            console.log(url, newUrl.slice(5))
            gapi.savetodrive.render('savetodrive-div', {
                src: newUrl.slice(5), // to remove 'blob:'
                filename: 'file',
                sitename: 'site'
              });
        }
        xhr.send();
```

For more explanation,

The 'url' is a download url from firebase storage.

In the case of dropbox, Dropbox.save with the 'url' worked nicely.

But because of the CORS error, google drive didn't work with 'url'

I tried to set my firebase cors policy but it didn't work, so I'm trying with file object after downloading a file from the 'url'.